# invalid use of non-static data member (array)

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading, member, subscript-operator

I'm very new to C++, so this may be a pretty noobish issue, but I'm having trouble finding a solution. I've searched around for an answer, and the TA seems to have logically equivalent yet mysteriously working code, and we can't figure out why.

I'm trying to declare an array (named 'array) in my header file, and I keep getting some odd errors. When I declare it publicly as "int* array;" or "int array[];", the constructor tells me that this is an invalid use of a non-static data member. When I declare it private, it complains that the elements of the array are private.

The assignment deals with operator overloading, and deals with arrays with odd indices, such as from -3 to 5. Below is some code relevant to the problem:

```
// from the .cpp file
//constructor
IntArray::IntArray(int USER_DEFINED)
{
    if (USER_DEFINED < 1)
    {
        //return some kind of error
    }
    string name;
    setName();
    int lower = 0;
    int higher = USER_DEFINED - 1;
    array = new int[higher - lower];
    //int* p = &array[abs(lower)];
}

//overload
int IntArray::operator[](int i)
{
    if (i < lower || i > higher)
    {
        //return some sort of error
    }
    else
        return array[i - lower];
}

//from the .h file
class IntArray { 
     public: 
          int* array;
          int  operator[](int i);
};

//from the driver
void test1() {
    cout << "1. Array declared with single integer: IntArray a(10);" << endl << endl;
    csis << "1. Array declared with single integer: IntArray a(10);" << endl << endl;
    IntArray a(10);
    for(int i = a.low(); i <= a.high(); i++)
        a[i] = i * 10;
    a.setName("a");
    cout << a << endl;
    csis << a << endl;
    wait();
}`
```

a[i] = i * 10; is where the compiler complains.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That overload of `operator[]` doesn't fit the proper lvalue or rvalue signature.

Comment: @chris: It looks fine to me. It is a bit strange to have an `operator[]` return by value, but it should be valid.

Comment: @BillyONeal, If it's for an rvalue, it should be a `const` function.

Comment: @chris: There are a lot of things it should be. But as it stands, it is legal.

Comment: @BillyONeal, Legal doesn't always mean proper :) Expected semantics (working on constant objects) have a role as well, and that bug will probably resurface later.

Answer (score 4):

Your `operator[]` returns an `int`, which is returned to the caller as an unnamed temporary; an "rvalue". (Historically so called because it is the set of operations allowed to occur on the right half of an assignment statement)

A statement like `a[i] = i * 10;` wouldn't make sense, because you would be modifying the unnamed temporary result of `a[i]`. If you want someone to be able to modify the `int` in the memory pointed to `IntArray::array`, then return a reference instead.